# Error "handshake_failure" when trying to connect to ssl url with TLSv2 in java

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I am trying to connect to a SSL url with TLSv2.I am using Java 8 and  trying to connect through the HttpsURLConnection library.My code is given below

### Code :

```
        Proxy p = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("myProxy", 8080));
       if (true) {
           SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            TrustManager[] trustAll
                    = new TrustManager[] {new TrustAllCertificates()};
            sslContext.init(null, trustAll, new java.security.SecureRandom());

            HttpsURLConnection
                    .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            // Open HTTPS connection
            URL url = new URL("https://myurl.com");
            httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(p);
            httpsConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

            // Trust all hosts
            httpsConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new TrustAllHosts());
            // Connect
            httpsConnection.connect();
        }
```

### TrustAllCertificates Class :

```
public class TrustAllCertificates implements X509TrustManager {

@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

I am getting the following error

### Error :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at com.journaldev.spring.controller.HomeController.sendSoapRequest(HomeController.java:133)
at com.journaldev.spring.controller.HomeController.user(HomeController.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried changing the SSLContext.getInstance("SSL") to "TLSv2" and "TLSv1",But still getting same issue.Can anyone help me out with letting me know what to do in this

Comment: looks like you are using a Proxy which is listening in port 8080. Is this proxy support SSL TLS V1.2 as well?

Comment: @AdiOhana : Yes It supports .The same proxy i used to send SOAP request through SOAP UI for the same url.And from SOAP UI ,it works fine

Comment: I don't see the piece of code for adding the JKS to the SSLContext in the client..are you using certificate validation?

Comment: @AdiOhana : I have turned off the certificate validation in this using TrustAllCertificates class.Kindly let me know what should be done next.I am not sure what is the JKS for or how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue.The ciphers were not supporting in my case.So what i did was ,I downloaded "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)" zip from additional resources of Oracle's download page.The zip contains two jars "local_policy.jar" and "US_export_policy.jar" which has to be replaced in "<%JDK_Location%>\jre\lib\security" folder in my system.Then i was able to access the server with no exception.Hope it helps someone facing similar kind of issue